# Meaning of 1/1 and 1/2 beneath pedaling marking

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

Today I saw 1/1 and 1/2 written in one of my pieces beneath the pedal markings.

[image: Picture of ambiguous notation]

Do these have a meaning or is it a misprint?

Comment: @EpicGuy The much more relevant statement would have been "they aren't time signatures as they're written *in small print directly below a pedal marking*".

Comment: @KyleStrand Ah yes I didn't really clarify where they were. And the piece is called "Death by Pasta" by Sonny Chua.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a little hard to tell without seeing the music, but these are unlikely to be time-signatures and marcato markings. The "^" is probably a **variable pedal mark**, particularly if it is connected to the lines showing the pedal markings. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Pedal_marks) page shows how this is usually used, it

> More accurately indicates the precise use of the sustain pedal. The
>   extended lower line tells the player to keep the sustain pedal
>   depressed for all notes below which it appears. The inverted "V" shape
>   (∧) indicates the pedal is to be momentarily released, then depressed
>   again.

This also explains the use of 1/1 and 1/2, indicating either full or half lifting of the pedal. As [this](http://crosseyedpianist.com/tag/pedal-markings/) page explains, you can have many "degrees of pedal, such as half, quarter or even eighth pedal."