# Name for pedal markings

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, terminology

Is there any name for the inverted V (∧) in pedal markings? Or are they just known as part of pedal markings?

Answer (score 1):

These are **variable pedal markings**. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Pedal_marks) page for more info. They indicate that you should momentarily lift the pedal at the points indicated.

[This](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/17887/9198) post shows how these marks can also be used to indicate partial lifting of the pedal.

Comment: So the V's aren't called anything else?

Comment: I'm curious... Do you have a source for it only indicating a *partial* release (as opposed to merely a momentary release)? I don't recall ever hearing that, and the internet pages I'm finding this morning aren't telling me that either. (OTOH, I also didn't know what they were called; good to know they have name).

Comment: @Bob - it says 'momentarily' released in what I found. Open to conjecture?

Comment: @Bob.Check out Ilinca Vartic's articles (youtube, etc.) about pedalling. It's enlightening.

Comment: Hello all. Yes, I'll change. Getting it mixed up with another answer to same OP I did earlier. Thanks both.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find an appropriate title for the mark, but the purpose of half pedalling, and half lifting is that lower sounding notes will continue to sound during this procedure, while the higher notes will effectively be stifled.Except of course the very high strings on a piano which are not damped anyway.(Usually the top octave or so).Other pedal actions give effects such as allowing the notes to sound on in a subtle way with the pedal down a little. Others will no doubt enlighten us all with far better explanations (I hope).